# Undo button on Plotly figure

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python

Is there a way to add 'undo' button to a plotly graph (using python)?

For instance- on a scatter plot, when I change the zoom level multiple times to focus on an interesting area and I want to go back to previous zoom level instead of using the reset axis button that reverts back to initial zoom level.

I saw there is a configuration value named 'queueLength' that "Sets the length of the undo/redo queue." according to it's description ([here](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/blob/master/src/plot_api/plot_config.js)), but I never understand how to use the mentioned undo/redo tools.

Thanks!

Comment: I'd like to know the answer to your question too. Meanwhile, you may perhaps use a [rangeslider](https://plotly.com/python/range-slider) and/or the scroll wheel of your mouse to adjust [zoom](https://plotly.com/python/configuration-options/#enabling-scroll-zoom) levels as a workaround.